# RavenDB Simple Index Creation

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm having a problem adding analyzer with the raven db interface.

When writing StandartAnalyzer or SimpleAnalyzer
it never saves.

[image]

Comment: Maybe Standard instead of Standart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer` and `Lucene.Net.Analysis.SimpleAnalyzer`

Comment: Nope.  After saving the index and refreshing the page - the "Analyzer" box is empty.

Comment: If you're not using it in production now, you should consider using later builds. Also take a look at the [release plans](http://ayende.com/blog/159169/you-release-too-often-you-donrsquo-t-release-enough-ravendb-plans) posted today.

Comment: Do you mean we should use the unstable?
Is the latest here:
http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/RavenDB-Unstable
Will be good enough?

If not, can you please provide me with a link to the needed version?

Thanks Again.

Comment: Yes, if you're not using it in production environment, that should work. Your link shows the latest versions. You can also get them [using NuGet with the -Prerelease and -Version flags for the Install-Package command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18058/discussion-between-devaffair-and-alexander-zeitler)